# Games are playing but very slow response and poor graphics

Tags: graphics, games

The graphics memory of my notebook is 2.5 GB , 1 GB dedicated memory. After installing Ubuntu 12.04, I activated the graphics card from Applications->additional drivers. I have dual boot, all high end games are working fine without any issues in Windows 7 but games are very slow in Ubuntu.

The games that I have installed in Ubuntu are Warzone2100, 0AD, ManiaDrive and Scorched 3D.  All the games are playing but very slow response and poor graphics. I have seen the gameplay videos of these games, they are good esp Warzone2100 and 0AD.

My Questions:

1. How to check the graphics memory ?
2. Why the games respond very slow ? Please provide the solution to improve it.

I love using Ubuntu but for games I depend on Windows 7.. I do not expect to run high end graphics games in Ubuntu but I would like to play Warzone and 0AD without any problem. Help me.

System info:

Product Name: HP g6-1209ax

Product Number: A3V45PA

Microprocessor: 2.3 GHz/1.4 GHz AMD Quad-Core A6-3400M

Microprocessor Cache: 4 MB L2 cache

Memory: 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Max Memory: Upgradeable to 8 GB DDR3

Video Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6470M (1 GB DDR3 dedicated)

Display: 15.6" High-Definition LED HP Brightview Display (1366 x 768)

Hard Drive: 500 GB SATA (5400 rpm)

Answer (score 0):

To check your graphics memory you can install hard info, it should be under PCI devices.
with regards to games running slow, it seems to be quite common in ubuntu, I checked in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsAti and your video card is not offically supported, not yet anyway, that doesn't mean it can't work well, though. I assume that you installed the proprietry drivers, if you didn't you should. here's some info on ways to do that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI